# Button finish activity after 2 press is WRONG: Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back

I want the button to finish the activity. Why do I have to press it TWICE for it to finish, I do not want this. Note, I have to press the button twice before the activity ends, which I do not  want.

MainActivity Class:

```
 private Runnable updateOkay= new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    if (true) {
      Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkTimerNotification.class);
     startActivity(i); }
```

WorkTimerNotification class:

```
 public Button confirmButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_timer_notification);

    confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmOK_button);
    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
     }
    }
```

Comment: you do not need to click it twice, for it to finish() by moving off the screen, click it once and it will be ok. try it

Comment: Provide some more info, are there other activities, what is your program flow?

Comment: Are you sure the runnable is executed  only once? Otherwise the button might have to be pressed twice because WorkTimerNotification class is started more than once.

Comment: The class is not started more than once in the case that the if statement is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file.